# PHP HREF URL Link not opening webpage

Tags: php, url, href

I have an HREF link which allows my users to click a button(image) and they then get routed to the payment engine. Based on the clients account type depends on which link he is sent to. What i have done is i have used a string in my HREF and then declared the string as a SQL statement which checks the clients account type and brings back the correct link. I have check the SQL script is working fine and brining back the correct link BUT when i click on the button a get a Error 404 ie its not finding the link on my localhost but i want it to go to the internet not my local host.  My code:

```
<div class="paynow"><a href="$payfastl"><img src="./img/paynow.png"> 
</a></div>

$userloggedin= $_SESSION['user_id'];

$payfastl=("SELECT Payment_Link.Link
FROM Payment_Link
inner join phpro_users on Payment_Link.Amount=phpro_users.Amount_Due
where phpro_users.User_Id= $userloggedin
order by phpro_users.Date_Created
limit 1");
```

Can anyone pick up my mistake ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL statements are not URLs.

You need to run your SQL through your database, get the URL back, and then use the URL in your `href` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, fully agree my attempt at doing this was to use a string with a property of the select statement bringing back the link in the href. Not sure if any other way to do it.  Do you have any ideas ?